# PHP regex pattern modification needed

Tags: php, regex

I'm sure this has been asked before and I did read through a lot of posts but nothing helped me.  Since my regex knowledge is limited I thought I would ask for help.

I need to validate some user input (zip code format).  Only certain characters are allowed:
`A`, `N`, `CC`, `?`, space ( ) and hyphen (`-`).

**Sample Input Data**

```
$input = "CC-XNNNNN", "ANNNNAAA", "AAAA NAA", "ANN ????"
```

**Regex Pattern**

```
$pattern = "(?:C{2})*|A*|N*|\?*|\-*|\ *"
```

**PHP Code**

```
if(preg_match('/' . $pattern . '/', $input))
{
 echo("pass<br>" . PHP_EOL);
}
else
{
 echo("fail<br>" . PHP_EOL);
}
```

I don't think I need to use anchors, because the allowed characters can be in any position.  With the above code I get 'pass' but I should get 'fail' (X not allowed).  I've looked this over so much I can't see the forest for the trees anymore.

Can anyone see what I've done wrong?  OR is regex the wrong tool for this?

Comment: When it comes to regex, I suggest using an online service for testing such as https://regex101.com/. If I put your pattern in there, I get an error message about the `|?` sequence being invalid

Comment: Do the letters you listed in your question represent something here, like A == alpha, N == numeric, or are these letters literals in your input?

Comment: @Chris Haas, I did use regex101.com and if I copy/paste my pattern I don't get any error message.  But it never fails even when it should.

Comment: @Tangentially Perpendicular, yes they do but that's not what I want tested.  I only want the user to enter the allowed valid characters I listed.

Comment: Thanks @CharlesEF, it was a formatting error between markdown and HTML. I made a quick demo of your code and they all appear to pass: https://3v4l.org/QpiKQ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following regex, written and tested with shown samples. Online demo of regex is: [Regex online demo](https://regex101.com/r/fBuMb3/2)

```
^(?:[aA]|[nN]|[cC]{2}|\?|\s+|-)+$
```

Explanation: Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
^(?:       ##Starting a non capturing group from starting of value here.
[aA]       ##Checking if its either small a or capital A here.
|[nN]      ##OR if its N or n here.
|[cC]{2}   ##OR its c or C here with 2 occurrences.
|\?        ##Or its ? as a literal character.
|\s+       ##OR its one or more occurrences of spaces.
|-         ##OR its a dash
)+         ##Closing non capturing group and + will make sure only these characters follow
$          ##till end of the value.
```

Also I have matched characters with their small letter form also in case you don't need that we could change above to: `^(?:A|N|C{2}|\?|\s+|-)+$` then.

Comment: I've only had time for a small amount of testing.  I tried with your pattern (the one with no lowercase).  I've found 1 problem with my 4th input sample (ANN ????).  Your pattern reports 'fail' when it should be 'pass'.  I tried adding *, to allow for zero or many but that didn't work.

Comment: @CharlesEF, I have checked by putting ANNN ???? and it worked fine for me see this once https://regex101.com/r/ugdAzn/1 let me know how it goes for you, thank you.

Comment: Yes, it appears to work there but it reports 'fail' when I use my PHP code posted above.  I will look into it more and report back later.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: @CharlesEF, your welcome, cheers and happy learning

Comment: I found the problem.  It was the space character.  I copy/pasted from Excel into my editor but who knows what happened.  In my editor I backspaced and then hit the space bar.  Now it passes the test.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use a character class instead of alternating between the single characters.

To also match the lowercase variant, you can use the `/i` flag

```
^(?:[AN? -]|CC)+$
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `[AN? -]` Match one of the listed characters
  - `|` Or
  - `CC` Match `CC`
- `)+` Close the group and repeat it 1+ times
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/2yCJsK/1)

Comment: Thanks for your solution, it appears to work just as well as RavinderSingh13's answer.  He helped me first so he got the credit.  Thank you for your input.